# How to cut a variable to 20 equal segments (for example) for several columns in a dataset in R

Tags: r, bigdata, revolution-r

I know how to do it for one single variable. We can use equal.count() or a combination of quantile() and cut().
anyone knows an aggregate function to do this for 100 columns at the same time?

I know I can write a loop but it is slow. Is there a faster way? Because I am looking at a big data issue and possible solution using revolution R is welcome too. Thanks advance!

To clarify:  I was trying to break every single column to 20 ranges not just by the first column. I am not trying to split the dataset but trying to transform variables to different ranges . Hope it clarifies. Thank you a lot

Comment: you want to "cut" each variable and use the quantiles as breaks?

Comment: Yes and I want something like cut() to convert it to categorical directly.

Comment: Great question. I believe i'll use this soon for my own analysis. I've added a faster method using set()!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the g argument in cut2() to choose the breaks your will cut the variable into.

```
require(data.table)
require(Hmisc)

set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(x1 = rnorm(10e5, 50, 50),
                 x2 = rnorm(10e5, 30, 50),
                 x3 = rnorm(10e5, 20, 50),
                 x4 = rnorm(10e5, 10, 50),
                 x5 = rnorm(10e5, 10, 50)
)


cut_qt <- DT[,sapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) cut2(x, g = 4)), ]


print(cut_qt)

head(cut_qt)
x1               x2               x3               x4               x5                
[1,] "[  16.3, 50.0)" "[-199.6, -3.8)" "[ -13.7, 20.0)" "[ -23.8, 10.0)" "[ -23.74,  9.97)"
[2,] "[  16.3, 50.0)" "[  63.6,257.4]" "[  20.0, 53.7)" "[-218.7,-23.8)" "[-222.34,-23.74)"
[3,] "[  83.7,292.5]" "[  -3.8, 29.9)" "[ -13.7, 20.0)" "[  43.7,247.6]" "[ -23.74,  9.97)"
[4,] "[  50.0, 83.7)" "[  63.6,257.4]" "[ -13.7, 20.0)" "[  10.0, 43.7)" "[-222.34,-23.74)"
[5,] "[  50.0, 83.7)" "[  29.9, 63.6)" "[-232.5,-13.7)" "[  10.0, 43.7)" "[-222.34,-23.74)"
[6,] "[  83.7,292.5]" "[  29.9, 63.6)" "[-232.5,-13.7)" "[  43.7,247.6]" "[ -23.74,  9.97)"
```

As this is slow considering the OP is dealing with a large dataset:

```
> system.time(DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) cut2(x, g = 4)), ])
   user  system elapsed 
  37.66    0.00   38.70
```

**ALTERNATIVE METHOD USING set()**

```
# 1) Calculate Quantiles
q <- DT[,sapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) quantile(x)), ]
q
x1          x2         x3         x4          x5
0%   -189.95953 -199.574605 -232.54139 -218.74362 -222.343247
25%    16.28067   -3.797748  -13.72424  -23.76578  -23.736187
50%    49.98701   29.938932   20.01473   10.03740    9.967671
75%    83.66663   63.614604   53.74529   43.73047   43.676887
100%  292.53835  257.368361  280.64704  247.64500  277.418083


# 2) Modify the existing DT with the categorical variables using set

cols_to_fix <- names(DT)

for (j in 1:length(cols_to_fix)){
  column <- cols_to_fix[j] 
  brk = q[,j]
  val = cut2(DT[[column]], cuts = brk)
  set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value = val)
}

system.time(for (j in 1:length(cols_to_fix)){
  column <- cols_to_fix[j] 
  brk = q[,j]
  val = cut2(DT[[column]], cuts = brk)
  set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value = val)
}
  )
user  system elapsed 
4.71    0.00    4.83
```

Answer (score 1):

New version:

Make a 20 column, 100 row data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(20, sample(1:100)))
```

Split each column by the deciles of that column; this produces a 2D list of dimensions 10 x 20:

```
pieces <- vapply(df, function(x) split(x, cut(x, quantile(x, (0:10)/10))), vector("list", 10))
```

You can use matrix notation to access the contents

```
pieces[[2, 1]]
# [1] 20 12 14 16 11 19 17 13 18 15
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't been clear.  I was trying to break every single column to 20 ranges not just by the first column. I am not trying to break the dataset but trying to transform variables to different ranges . Hope it clarifies. Thank you a lot!

Comment: so you just want to take each column and apply `cut` at the `quantile`s?

Comment: @rawr I believe he just want to convert numeric data into categorical and use quantiles as breaks.

Comment: Yes that's what I want. THanks @MartínBel !

Comment: @MartínBel, nice reading comprehension; I don't think I would have ever figured it out

Answer (score 1):

You used `revolution-r` tag so I assume you are running Revolution R. If your data are in Revolution XDF format you can use rxDiscretize from [RevoEnhancements](https://github.com/RevoEnhancements/RevoEnhancements) package. It creates the binnings for all variables in the data set at once and produces an object which you can use as transformation in rxDataStep function. From the help page:

```
library(RevoEnhancements)

# Equal Freq
discTransforms <- rxDiscretize(~ cost, 
                               data = claimsXdf, 
                               type = "freq", 
                               nBins = 1000, 
                               subscript = "disc", 
                               sep = "_")

x <- rxDataStep(inData = claimsXdf, transforms = discTransforms)
```